# Unwanted line in the raster data (DEM and DEM derived indices)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem

[image]I am getting unwanted parallel lines in the raster data (see image). I was deriving different indices like slope, terrain ruggedness index, topographic wetness index etc. Prior to calculation I also reprojected the RAW DEM to a projected coordinate system.
Please help me out of this. [image]

Comment: Are the lines still there if you zoom all the way in, or do they only appear in the pyramid/overview (zoomed-out) view of the raster?

Comment: @SonofaBeach yup they are still there.

Comment: Are they only in the TWI raster? If they only occur in that dataset it would strongly suggest that the cause of them is by the algorithm employed to compute the TWI value.

Comment: @Hornbydd No, it on every raster i computed from the DEM

Comment: So the lines are in your base dataset, the DEM?

Comment: @Hornbydd I've used ASTER V3 DEM 30m, i don't know where's the problem. Files - ASTGTMV003_N31E076_dem, ASTGTMV003_N31E077_dem, ASTGTMV003_N32E076_dem, ASTGTMV003_N32E077_dem. After downloading them I mosaiced data to new raster then clip with the AOI then reprojected the clipped raster to UTM (projected coordinate system WGS 1984 UTM 43N).

Comment: Can you share the DEM say on dropbox/google drive so others can examine it?

Comment: @Hornbydd https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKeNhKRlapWK-6bxKzVwNAhhnJXFbj18/view?usp=sharing